# what can a hacker do with stolen cookies?

Tags: cookies, beef

What if a hacker steals my cookies for example using BeEF or something else. What can they do with this information? Can they get any passwords or something?

Comment: Cookies are just small text spaces where a site can store, well, anything. It's like asking "what if a thief steals my notebook; what can they do with the information?" It all depends on the information that has been stored and what protections are in place to prevent misuse/abuse....

Answer (score 2):

Session cookies are pieces of information that allow you to maintain state across multiple HTTP requests (which is by design a stateless protocol).

In other words, what allows you to login to gmail, reboot your computer and go back to gmail without having to login is the presence of a session cookie that, on the server side, matches an active session.

So, hackers who can steal your session cookies will be able to impersonate you (within certain limitations) on the websites you are logged in to. For example Gmail, Twitter, Facebook, eBay, etc.

Can they get your passwords? Not directly, although depending on the implementation of the applications they got access to, they may be able to find hints, fragments or the actual password set to that account.

Comment: Unless the site stores the password in the cookie, as was done in days of yore... https://www.troyhunt.com/how-to-build-and-how-not-to-build/

Comment: The scope for getting it wrong is virtually boundless, so I have no trouble believing that, even if it had not been documented.

Comment: so he can log in to my accounts as if he was me?that means if he can log into my gmail he can also hack facebook for example by asking for verification email .... and one more question can he see stored passwords on my google account if i set my gmail to auto login?

Comment: @nonope2454 you've missed the point of our comments. It is possible that stealing a cookie could do those things in general, but that does not mean that it is possible specifically for Gmail and Facebook.